# Rewrite rule to HTTPS except when on localhost

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15119044/51) as the basis for trying to add a rewrite rule to my web.config file. I want it to match any url that is not running on localhost in order to force https.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite> <!-- force https - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15119044/51 -->
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^((?!localhost).)*$"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I am trying to use a [negative lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/51) in order to only match url's that do not include "localhost" within the url. But this is not working.

So how should this rule be set up in order to only rewrite non-localhost url's?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this condition:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" /> 
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Using a `negate` condition against the `localhost` pattern should do the trick.

Comment: Results in `HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.`

Comment: Same error. I suspect that it may be related to the action referencing a grouping - `{R:1}` - which is no longer being included in the matching regex.

Comment: Yes that is true, let me suggest you something for that also.

Comment: If you are using custom ports (like localhost:6002) then look at @firstTimeCaller answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23554829/237858

Answer (score 59):

Adding to anubhava's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947827/176868), you can replace the add element for localhost with the following 2 entries to cater for both localhost and 127.0.0.1 with optional ports e.g localhost:59400 which is the case when debugging through visual studio and IIS

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
```

With the original answer, localhost:123 would be redirected to https which may not be desirable.

Comment: this one worked for me. anubhava's answer doesn't consider  the localhost:XXXX case (port)

Comment: this works for me except if I navigate to root ("/").  then for some reason it is redirecting me to HTTPS.

Comment: @MikeW I am getting the same issue when navigating to root.  Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: here is my entire rule - seems to be working...  <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>

Comment: @drewid I had the same problem accessing root & resolved it by setting the following attribute on the conditions element: logicalGrouping="MatchAll". So now my element is: <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

Comment: Can you also provide an example with a specific port number? like http://localhost:15536

Comment: @MikeW maybe your browser cached a previous redirect? In my case, clearing the browser cache fixed the issue. I read in a blog post: "Always remember when you debug a redirect (specifically a 301) that browsers tend to cache them and that it can lead to frustration when you change the rule but nothing happens…" see here: https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2015/02/21/rewrite-redirect-iis.html

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression updated, this works for me, with a custom Port

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(localhost)(:\d+)" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(127.0.0.1)(:\d+)" negate="true" />
```

Comment: Nitpick: the dots have special meaning in POSIX regular expressions, and need to be escaped. So 127.0.0.1 should be 127\.0\.0\.1