# Rewrite rule to WWW except when on localhost

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

For SEO optimization reason, I get all requests to `http://Example.com` redirected to `http://www.Example.com`. The problem is that when working on local, requests to `localhost` get redirected as well.

I tried the suggestion in this [Rewrite rule to HTTPS except when on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947827/27194) answer with no luck.

Here is my actual redirection rule located in `Web.Config` (*hopefully it can help someone that is looking for Rewrite rule to WWW*):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirect example.com to www.example.com">
          <match url="^(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a rule as follows

```
<rule name="redirect example.com to www.example.com">
   <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.*" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
   </rule>
</rules>
```

It combines two conditions with "MatchAll" where the first input is similar to one you already have (you can use yours if you want) and the second one is to check for localhost. Note, that you would probably need to use {R:0} and I also changed match url to .*

You can also use different web.configs (debug and release). Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'd like to keep a single but smarter web.config, it is less error prone. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work,  localhost:3064 still get redirected to  www.example.com